# How to extend a native's component's props TypeScript interface in a stateless, functional component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-props

For consistent styling, the React Native docs recommend writing a `<CustomText />` text component that wraps the native `<Text />` component.

While this is easy to do, I can't work out with TypeScript 2 how to make `<CustomText />` have all of the props from `<Text />` without having to redeclare them.

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';


interface Props {
    children?: any
}

const CustomText: React.SFC<Props> = (props) => (
    <Text {...props}>
        {props.children}
    </Text>
);
```

And if I try to use it with `<CustomText numberOfLines={1} />` it will result in an error

```
TS2339: Property 'numberOfLines' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
```

In `react-native.d.ts`, I see that there's this export:

```
export interface TextProperties extends React.Props<TextProperties> {

    /**
     * Specifies should fonts scale to respect Text Size accessibility setting on iOS.
     */
    allowFontScaling?: boolean

    /**
     * Line Break mode. Works only with numberOfLines.
     * clip is working only for iOS
     */
    lineBreakMode?: 'head' | 'middle' | 'tail' | 'clip'

    /**
     * Used to truncate the text with an elipsis after computing the text layout, including line wrapping, such that the total number of lines does not exceed this number.
     */
    numberOfLines?: number

    /**
     * Invoked on mount and layout changes with
     *
     * {nativeEvent: { layout: {x, y, width, height}}}.
     */
    onLayout?: ( event: LayoutChangeEvent ) => void

    /**
     * This function is called on press.
     * Text intrinsically supports press handling with a default highlight state (which can be disabled with suppressHighlighting).
     */
    onPress?: () => void

    /**
     * @see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style
     */
    style?: TextStyle

    /**
     * Used to locate this view in end-to-end tests.
     */
    testID?: string
}
```

but I'm not sure how to extend it to take advantage of it in my component's `Props` interface.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to make your `Props` interface extends `TextProperties`:

```
interface Props extends TextProperties {
    children?: any
}
```

---

#### Edit

You need to import it first:

```
import { Text, TextProperties } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I tried that, but it errors with `TS2304: Cannot find name 'TextProperties'`. Even tried adding the `<reference path />` to no avail :(

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Try, `import { TextProps } from 'react-native'` rather than, `TextProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextProps } from 'react-native'

export default function MText({ children, style }: TextProps) {
  return <Text style={[styles.text, style]}>{children}</Text>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
  },
})
```